# Solving a sangaku circle problem using a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, sangaku

From the question ["Sangaku Circle Geometry Problem"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652402/sangaku-circle-geometry-problem):

> [image]
>
> Given $a$ and $b$, find $c$. (The enclosing circular segment is not necessarily a semicircle.)

The answer is

> $$c = \frac{a(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})^2}{4(3b + \sqrt{ab} )}$$

I'm curious how one would solve the given puzzle using a system of equations.

My first attempt was to describe all circles via the circle formula:
$$(x−m_1)^2+(y−m_2)^2=r^2$$ with $$r=a,b,c,d$$ accordingly for every circle
and equate the circle equations of touching circles in certain points.
But I didn't got the clue how I should state the midpoints of the circles.

Maybe someone could give me a little push in the right direction.

Comment: That's not much of a start, really.  Why not go through accepted answer to the original question?  Maybe you can find some good ways to simplify it...at a quick glance, it  looks like it might not be optimal (though with these Sangaku problems it's often very hard to tell).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Of course i read through the "geometric" answer, but the author of the question also stated that he used some system of nonlinear equations, like the circle-equation, but was hoping to get a geometric solution, whilst he has got a solution using linear algebra. I try to compare the both approaches, but am stuck with the system of equations.